# Twain sample Data source and virtual scanner

Tags: virtual, twain

I am using this link for a virtual scanner

http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/
But there are no data sources being populated.
Connect to datasource is disabled.
What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that, even after installing the Data Source Manager, you might still not see a Scanner in the Sample Application. This is because your Application only "sees" Drivers of the same Architecture, e.g. 32 or 64-Bit. Most Drivers are still in 32-Bit, so try to compile your program accordingly (I worked with this in Visual Studio mostly).

Answer (score -1):

https://sourceforge.net/p/twain-samples/bugs/40/
I figured it out. I had to install thee DS.